# Access show fields based on value

Tags: forms, ms-access, listbox

I'm trying to make a form with Access.

If the value in 'Activiteiten' is 'Onderzoek' I want the field 'Penvoerder' and 'Subsidie' to appear.
And if the value 'Activiteiten' is something else I want different values to appear.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

I've tried multiple settings in the properties of the fields. But this didn't work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the *OnCurrent* event:

```vb
Dim Visible As Boolean

Visible = (Me!Activiteiten.Value = "Onderzoek")
Me!Penvoerder.Visible = Visible
```